# Couchdb development server access

Tags: couchdb

I am totally new to couchdb,

How can i expose the service into a local development remote server ? (after in a future step expose it public)

I try to install on a remote development server besides i am not using Digital Ocean server i am using this tutorial : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-couchdb-and-futon-on-ubuntu-14-04

I could not access with a web browser after install and start couchdb service with

`couchdb -b`

Wich return the default message : Apache CouchDB has started, time to relax.

Also from comand line i could:

`curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/`

And receive the correct message.

How can i access via web browser this development server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't know for sure, since I don't know your setup, but I'm guessing that you're trying to access the database from a different machine then the one it's running on. And I assume you know what IP to use to get to your remote, and that leads me to believe that your problem is that the port is not open (or not forwarded correctly) to your couchDB server.

A standard couchDB installation should be accessible, from a web-browser.